# Mutating/Updaing array of objects while destructuring object properties not mutating the array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have recently discovered an interesting behavior while mapping my array of objects and using destructuring og the object properties

```
var arr = [
  {name: 'John'},
  {name: 'Peter'},
]

arr.map(({name}) => {
    name = 'Lars'
  return name;
})

console.log(arr) //prints [{name: 'Johh'}, {name: 'Peter'}]
```

Seems like the destructured properties are only re-assigned to the object, but the object is not re-assigned to the array.

If I drop using destructured values in my map function it and keep object reference it is going to work.

```
 arr.map((item) => {
        item.name = 'Lars'
 })
   
 console.log(arr) //prints [{name: 'Lars'}, {name: 'Lars'}]
```

Is there any way to mutate the array while using destructured properties in a map or a similar function ?

Comment: This is not specific to destructuring. What you are doing is the same as `var name = item.name; name = 'Lars';`. JavaScript uses "pass/copy by value", so when you do `var name = item.name;`, `name` is assigned a copy of the value of `item.name`, not a "reference" to the `item.name` property. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath: That doesn't matter. You would see the same behavior no matter the data type of `name`.

Comment: @FelixKling how come? so for primitive type a copy is getting created whereas for object same memory is pointed right?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath: Consider `var item = {name: {foo: 'bar'}}; var name = item.name; name = {bar: 'baz'}; console.log(item.name);`. `item.name` won't change no matter its value. It seems you are mixing two concepts: reference/value-type values and "copy/pass by value/reference" (which only affects variables/parameters).

Comment: @FelixKling you are right. I just check this `let arr1 = [{c:'a'},{c:'b'}]; arr1.forEach(e => e = {c:'11'})`.

Comment: "*Is there any way to mutate the array while using destructured properties in a map or a similar function ?*" - No. And you should not use `map` anyway to mutate objects - the `map` method is meant to create a **new** array!